# Dynamical radio button group validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

What is the best way to validate to ensure at least one in every group is checked, so in the following example groups are `name1`, `name2`, `name3`?

**Example**

```
<input type="radio" name="name1">
<input type="radio" name="name1"> 
<input type="radio" name="name1"> 

<input type="radio" name="name2"> 
<input type="radio" name="name2"> 
<input type="radio" name="name2">

<input type="radio" name="name3"> 
<input type="radio" name="name3"> 
<input type="radio" name="name3">
```

I know I can wrap a div around each one and then check each radio button in the div, but I am looking for a more dynamic solution. So, if in future more radio buttons are added, the jQuery code would not need to be altered or the divs would not need to be added - I hope this makes sense.

Comment: why dont you add a class or a id attribute for each group? and you can validate using that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [jquery.validate.js](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js) library to help you solve this question, check out their [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html)

If you use the library it would be as simple as,

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" validate="required:true">
<input type="radio" name="name1">
<input type="radio" name="name1">

<input type="radio" name="name2" validate="required:true">
<input type="radio" name="name2">
<input type="radio" name="name2">
```

Check out the [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apdR2/): This finds all the different names for radio buttons and then runs through all those different groups and makes sure that there is at least one checked, if not it will throw an alert.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var names = [];

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
        // Creates an array with the names of all the different checkbox group.
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });

    // Goes through all the names and make sure there's at least one checked.
    for (name in names) {
        var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + name + "']");
        if (radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
            alert('none checked in ' + name);
        } 
        else {
            // If you need to use the result you can do so without
            // another (costly) jQuery selector call:
            var val = radio_buttons.val();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you that is very useful solution - I didn't want to use a plugin just to validate radio buttons

Comment: what does names[$(this).attr('name')] = true; do?

Comment: @contactmatt because javascript arrays are associative, I believe setting `names['abc'] = true` essentially just adds `abc` to the array `names`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[name="name1"]:checked').length != 0
```

Or

```
$('[name="name1"]').is(':checked')
```

You could also do something a little more dynamic if you like:

```
var i = 1;
while ($('[name="name'+i+'"]').length != 0) {
    if ($('[name="name'+i+'"]').is(':checked')) {
        // at least one is checked in this group
    } else {
        // none are checked
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: If the names of the radio would be of that format this would be a pretty sweet solution, but I would think as developer he would want to give them a more significant name.