# check if dynamically loaded radio group is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons as given below.

```
<input type="radio" name="multi[1]" value="value-1">
<input type="radio" name="multi[1]" value="value-2">

<input type="radio" name="multi[2]" value="value-3">
<input type="radio" name="multi[2]" value="value-4">

<input type="radio" name="multi[3]" value="value-5">
<input type="radio" name="multi[3]" value="value-6">
<input type="radio" name="multi[3]" value="value-7">

<input type="radio" name="multi[n]" value="value-n">
<input type="radio" name="multi[n]" value="value-n">
<input type="radio" name="multi[n]" value="value-n">
```

If this groups are loaded dynamically, then how can we check if the option in every group is selected?

UPDATE:

```
num_group = 2;
for(i = 1; i <= num_group; i++){
   if(!$('input[name="multi['+i+']"]').is(':checked')){
         alert('Please select elective subjects '+i+'!');
         return false;
   }
}
```

How to calculate num_group dynamically? Here

Comment: Please show us the code that is not working. Remember that Stackoverflow is not here to code FOR you, but to help YOU code. Show us that you've put some effort into solving the problem yourself first.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229844/dynamical-radio-button-group-validation-in-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that the `document` is `ready` then bind a `change` event to the document.

This takes into account any elements that are dynamiclly loaded (the `change` function with still fire on these elements).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of validation that you would like to have.

If you are trying to validate the radio buttons at one specific time, for instance, when a user presses the submit button, you could just go through all the radios fairly simply, something like:

```
var max_radios = 1; // keep this updated as radio buttons are added
$('#validate').click(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= max_radios; i++) {
        console.log('Radio ' + i + ' is ' + 
                    ($('[name="multi[' + i + ']"]:checked').val() == undefined ? 'unchecked' : 'checked') + '<br />');
    }
})
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxLCZ/)

It's a little trickier if you want to have the validation live as a user adds/clicks the radio buttons.  In this case, as soon as a new radio button is added, you want to put up a validation message that indicates that the user should make a selection, and the validation message disappears once a value is selected.  Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: thanks! iterating over the radio group using multi[index] was useful, after some modification i was able to do this. (updated question)

However, I have one question though. How can we calculate the num_group here? If we are validating these field at the time of form submit.